# How to generate a multiline command/script by substitution of a field/s

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a command:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -pmypassword dev<file01.sql;
```

I have many sql files to run: file02.sql, file03.sql, ... file99.sql

I want to generate a bash script like this to run all these sql files sequentially.

a portion of the bash script reads like this:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -pmypassword dev<file01.sql;
mysql -h localhost -u root -pmypassword dev<file02.sql;
mysql -h localhost -u root -pmypassword dev<file03.sql;


mysql -h localhost -u root -pmypassword dev<file99.sql;
```

All these lines are of the same pattern, only file name (filexx.sql) changes.

All the filexx.sql are in the same directory.

I usually generate the bash script in Excel.  I know this can be done in bash easily, I just do not know how.  Could you advise on how to generate this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute those statements:

```
for fileid in $(seq 1 99); do
    filename=$(printf "file%02d.sql" $fileid)
    mysql -h localhost -u root -pmypassword dev < $filename
done
```

But if you only want to generate them:

```
for fileid in $(seq 1 99); do
    filename=$(printf "file%02d.sql" $fileid)
    echo "mysql -h localhost -u root -pmypassword dev < $filename"
done
```

Comment: If you use `seq` U could use format option: `seq -f file%02g.sql 1 99
`

Answer (score 0):

Bash's [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) to the rescue:

```
for file in file{00..99}.sql; do
    mysql -h localhost -u root -pmypassword dev < $file
done
```